# Change bar orientation plotly python based on screen size

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I have a Flask app and I have no idea if it is possible (and if so, how?) to get a python plotly bar graph with the bars vertically oriented for big screens and horizontally oriented when the screens are small. I tried with the configuration of the plot but it did not work. It would be perfect if the solution could simply use `python` directly, since my JS knowledge is practically nonexistent.

My HTML is:

```
<...>
    <!-- Graph and Calendar -->
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="text-start mb-2">Title of this section</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Title of the card</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- Interactive Graph Here -->
                    {{ graph_html | safe }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-4">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<...>
```

My Plotly in python is:

```
def create_bar_graph():
    data = [
        go.Bar(
            x=['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
            y=[10, 20, 15],
        )
    ]

    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Bar Graph',
        barmode='group',
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    # This didn't work:
    config = {'responsive': True}

    # Generate the graph HTML
    graph_html = pio.to_html(fig, full_html=False, config=config)

    return graph_html
```

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly Python library does not provide a native feature to change the orientation of the graph depending on the screen size. This type of responsive design is usually handled in the front-end using JavaScript and CSS.

But since you mentioned that your JavaScript knowledge is practically nonexistent, we can approach the issue in a different way, although it might not be the most efficient one. We can utilize the Flask framework and user agent information to identify the device type (or screen size roughly) from the server-side and create the appropriate graph based on that information.

First, install the `user-agents` library for parsing User-Agent headers:

```
pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents
```

Then, in your Flask route, you can determine if the user is on a mobile device or not, and pass that information to your `create_bar_graph()` function:

```
from flask import request
from user_agents import parse

@app.route('/your_route')
def your_route():
    user_agent = parse(request.headers.get('User-Agent'))
    is_mobile = user_agent.is_mobile

    graph_html = create_bar_graph(is_mobile)

    return render_template('your_template.html', graph_html=graph_html)
```

Now, modify your `create_bar_graph()` function to take an `is_mobile` parameter. If `is_mobile` is True, create a horizontal bar chart; if False, create a vertical bar chart:

```
def create_bar_graph(is_mobile):
    if is_mobile:
        data = [
            go.Bar(
                y=['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
                x=[10, 20, 15],
                orientation='h'
            )
        ]
    else:
        data = [
            go.Bar(
                x=['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
                y=[10, 20, 15],
            )
        ]

    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Bar Graph',
        barmode='group',
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    config = {'responsive': True}
    graph_html = pio.to_html(fig, full_html=False, config=config)

    return graph_html
```

This method has its limitations, as it assumes mobile devices have small screens and non-mobile devices have large screens, which is not always true. For a more accurate result, you should use front-end solutions (JavaScript, CSS media queries) to handle responsive design.

Comment: How much more complicated would be to use JS for this case?

Comment: @Jzbach Implementing this with JS would require interacting with Plotly's JS library. The high-level process would involve using JavaScript to detect the screen size, and then rendering the appropriate Plotly chart.

Comment: Ah, then no, the goal is to keep so much as possible in the python version of plotly. I thought about what you suggested, but I thought there was a simpler way or so. I will test it and accept the answer if it solved my problem. Thanks!